# C# - Dynamic casting using reflection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, casting

I am trying to pull values from a datatable object and populate an object for a webservice call dynamically, I have tried a few aproaches but narrowed them down to this, what it seems to be missing is the ability to reflect the target type and cast the object from the data table into one.

I'm scratching my head a lot here!

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in zAccount)
                {
                    object o = row[pi.Name];
                    if (o.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(a, o, null);
                    }
                 }
```

This gives me type conversion errors:

Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

So the ideal would be something like this:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in zAccount)
                {
                    object o = typeof(pi.GetType())row[pi.Name];
                    pi.SetValue(a, o, null);
                 }
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `row`?

Comment: DataRow I am iterating through a DataTable Object

Comment: Can't cast a string to Nullable<Boolean> so this has nothing to do with dynamic casting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that I use to do exactly what you are trying to do; convert types out of the DB.  Normally you could use `Convert.ChangeType`, but that doesn't work right with nullable types, so this method handles that case.

```
/// <summary>
/// This wrapper around Convert.ChangeType was done to handle nullable types.
/// See original authors work here: http://aspalliance.com/852
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to convert.</param>
/// <param name="conversionType">The type to convert to.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType)
{
  if (conversionType == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("conversionType");
  }
  if (conversionType.IsGenericType && conversionType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
  {
    if (value == null)
    {
      return null;
    }
    NullableConverter nullableConverter = new NullableConverter(conversionType);
    conversionType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType;
  }
  return Convert.ChangeType(value, conversionType);
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in zAccount)
{
  object o = ChangeType(row[pi.Name], pi.GetType());
  pi.SetValue(a, o, null);
}
```

---

*Edit:*

Actually, re-reading your post, your error message

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

makes it look like the type that you got back from the database is a `string`, but the property is of type `bool?` (nullable boolean) hence it can't convert it.

Comment: Maybe. I guess it depends what the actual value of `row[pi.Name]` is. If it is a string "true" or "false" then I think `Convert.ChangeType` might be able to make that a bool.  If it is the string "foo" then it will still throw some exception.

Comment: looks like it works fine.  And throwing up on a value like "foo" would be fine (and expected for a bool).  Likewise, an exception when trying to assign "foo" to an `int` is also expected.  +1 for me.

Comment: Works like a charm with some minor modification to my code, thanks for your time! +1

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing but it could be that your o is a string (like "false") and your property could be bool, and hence the error.

You could use Convert.ChangeType. It might help

Comment: That's probably the correct answer, but you should provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your rows contain data with types that do not match types of properties of account class.

Why it is so I don't know without seeing more of your code.